# Find general solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation $xy''+y'= -1$ with y(0)=1 and y(1)=0.

So far I tried to solve the homogeneous equation:

$y(x)=c_1ln(x)+c_2$

but when I try the boundary conditions I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: @projectilemotion Problem is, the intergrating factor method gives you y is in terms of log(x) which is undefined at 0, contradicting the boundary condition

Comment: That is what I did to find the homogeneous solution. But I do not understand how to find a particular solution.

Comment: @Divide1918 is rigth, that's where I am having problems

Comment: But what about the boundary conditions? if i set $c_1=0$ I would get y=0 would this be a correct answer?

Comment: If you set $w=y'$ you get $xw'+w=-1$. Do you know how to proceed from this point? You could also multiple both sides of $xy''+y'=-1$ by $x$ and get $$x^2y''+xy'=-x$$ The associated homogenous equation, namely $$x^2y''+xy'=0$$ is Cauchy$-$Euler. You can get two linearly independent solutions to the associated homogeneous equation by performing the substitution $y=x^n$. Once you have these you can proceed formally with variation of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y''+\dfrac1xy'+\dfrac1x=0$

$(y'x)'=y''x+\dfrac1xy'x=(y''+\dfrac1xy')x$

$\dfrac1x (y'x)'+\dfrac1x =0\implies (y'x)'=-1\implies y'x=-c$

$y=-c\log(x)+c'$, but $\log(0)$ is undefined, which means that $y=c'=1$.

Let $u(x)=ax^2+bx+c, u'(x)=2ax+b,u''(x)=2a\implies u''+\dfrac1xu'+\dfrac1x=4a+\dfrac1x(b+1)$, setting it to be the zero function gives $a=0, b=-1$, so $y=1-x$ is the solution

Comment: This equations can get so tricky! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Observe $-x$ is a solution (not satisfying the boundary condition);
add a suitable homogeneous solution, we see $y=1-x$ is the solution.

Comment: Can you explain me how do see that -x is a solution? @yuval

Comment: Substitute y=-x into the ode

Comment: got it! now for inhomogenous part how can I find a particular solution? @Divide1918

Comment: The quickest way to see $-x$ is by guessing. On the other hand, there is no $y$ term in the equation, so one may use $w=y'$ as the new unknown and reach the first order equation $xw'+w=-1$, which can be solved using integral factor, etc.

Comment: @Yuval but when I solve the first order equation I get the solution $y=c_1ln(x)+c_2$ and I can't apply the boundary condition y(0)=1 since ln(0) is undefined

Comment: So homo sol of y is constant.